# Python data from Django to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am busy on a Django app which analyzes a variety of data (largely using pandas) and then displays the results using Google charts.

Im having trouble figuring out the best way to pass my data from the django view.py which will generally be in a Pandas dataframe or a dict, through to be used in the template files (which use javascript for the google charts).

Here's some code showing a javascript function for displaying one of the charts. In this example i've hard coded the data into the chart (ie: The years and the sales have been manually typed in). However what needs to be done is to instead use the data from the pandas dataframe.

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales'],
        ['2004',  1000],
        ['2005',  1170],
        ['2006',  660],
        ['2007',  1030]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

It's easy enough to pass through single variables or even lists using the django template language {{ var }}. However im not entirely sure how to pass through more complicated dataframes, dicts, etc to be used in javascript functions.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to pass data or options or both?

Comment: I want to pass data from a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

**views.py:**

```
import json

def some_view_func(request):
    data = [
        ['Year', 'Sales'],
        ['2004',  1000],
        ['2005',  1170],
        ['2006',  660],
        ['2007',  1030]
    ]
    render(request, 'template.html', {'data': json.dumps(data)})
```

**template.html**:

```
<script>
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse({{data}}));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. My template loads however where the chart should be, there is nothing at all.

Comment: @darkpool what do you mean `there is nothing at all`?

Comment: My template should display a bar chart. That is what the javascript function does. However when trying your suggestion, the bar chart is not displayed. Nothing is displayed, ie: it does not work. If it helps, the code for the google chart that im using is from here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart. So I need to replace the hardcoded year/sales figures with a pandas dataframe passed through from views.py

Comment: @darkpool There are many possible reasons the chart is not displayed, but I can assure you that data is restored to an `Array` by `JSON.parse({{data}})`.You can `console.log` to check its value.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well if the chart is showing for you then I guess there must be something im doing wrong. It should be fairly simple. It is probably something with the google function (it uses the google API so I dont know how it works under the hood (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart). But all im doing is replacing their year/sales with my own data from views.py. Will have to keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: @darkpool Sorry but I didn't dive into google chart, so I'm not sure my solution can display the chart, I'm just answering your question of `how to pass through more complicated dataframes, dicts, etc to be used in javascript functions`.

Comment: ok thanks for trying. I will post a new question because im really stumped.

Comment: @darkpool Sure, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to achieve what I think you want

```
def view_func(request):
    data =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 5)) 

    render(request, 'template.html', {'data': data.to_html()})
```

See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) for extra details on CSS styling and other things.

Also implement data as 'safe' in your template as follows:

```
{{ data | safe }}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. However my template loads, but there is no bar chart. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: there is a library [django-pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pandas/0.2.0) for such kind of work.  See it might help

Comment: or skip to.html() in views.py and do this `{{ data.to_html(classes="table table-striped") | safe}}` in your template